# Python - Edit a module and put it back?

Tags: python

I use this module  https://github.com/Narcolapser/python-o365 and i want to add this to the message.py, below getBody

```
def getDate(self):
    '''get email date.'''
    return self.json['DateTimeReceived']
```

So far i got the egg out of the install folder and have unzipped it and edited the file, now i have no idea how to update it and put it back?

Am i going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update a file in python egg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736043/how-to-update-a-file-in-python-egg)

Comment: it says to use python setup.py, but where is setup.py?

Comment: @AlexW `setup.py` is the last file listed on the link you posted, here too https://github.com/Narcolapser/python-o365/blob/master/setup.py